# Use map to get the smallest positive number in tuple

Tags: python

```
x = (1,1,-13,8,5,0,4,-1,-4)


z = map(lambda x: min(x) >=0 , x)
```

Why is it when i try to `print(z)` I don't get 1 ?

Comment: You can use filter instead `>>> min(filter(lambda i: i >= 0, x))`

Comment: "Why is it when i try to print(z) I don't get 1 ?"  How can you reach to print statement, you must getting exception for `min(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code didn't work because, `lambda x`, will get individual items of the original tuple and you are passing them to `min`. That is why it fails. You can fix your program like this

```
print min(filter(lambda i: i >= 0, x))
# 1
```

We are doing the same thing with generator expression, like this

```
x = (1, 1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
print min(item for item in x if item > 0)
# 1
```

If you consider `0` also as a positive number, then

```
print min(item for item in x if item >= 0)
# 0
```

**Note:** This will throw an error, if none of the elements are positive or `x` is empty.

Comment: "min accepts only an iterable." --> `min(1, 2)` no iterator.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Let me check how it is implemented

Comment: I encounter multiple mistakes in OP question and looks he don't understand min and map both, I written an long answer, should I post,

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan By all means, please go ahead :)

Comment: Thanks for voting...I started very late and before I could post, post closed.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It was very detailed and it deserved it :) Also, it is not closed yet :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it when I try to `print(z)` I don't get `1`?

If you have code like:

```
z = map(lambda x: min(x) >=0 , x) # <-- exception 
#                   ^^^^^ 
print(z)
```

Then I doubt that control reaches to print statement. You must getting an exception at point I mentioned above in code as  comment. See its execution at my machine:

```
>>> x = (1, 1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
>>> z = map(lambda x: min(x) >= 0, x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>  # <--- First
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable  # <--- Second
```

Notice the error message. I marked 'first', the exception message says that you are getting exception in your lambda expression. 'Second' line I marked means exception is a TypeError!

> Why type error?

Because you are passing incorrect argument to `min( )` function within lambda expression. Check Python [documentation for `min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min). Function `min( )` can be called in two ways as follows:

```
>>> min(1, 2) # First: Multiple arguments  
1
>>> min([-1, 2, 3]) # Second: pass an iterator 
-1
>>> min([3]) # Infact you can pass iterator of single element, that will work
3
```

But how are you calling is something like as below:

```
>>> min(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable  # <---
>>>
```

Now again notice the exception message, it is same as we encounter in your code piece above a  "TypeError".

In `map( )` function, argument `x` in lambda expression is local that happen to be of type `int` (the tuple `x` second argument to `map( )` is collection of ints). You should also carefully read [`map(function, iterable, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function in documentation. In your code iterable is tuple `x`, and function is your lambda expression. And at very first step your lambda function called with `x[0]` that is `1` hence so you effectively called `min(1)` within lambda expression and that causes TypeError exception.